# Jquery Text Animation customization help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery sliding text animator. If you look at the example(http://blog.waiyanlin.net/2008/12/17/jquery-flying-text-with-fade-effect/), the active text that flies in disappears again after it has made its entrance. I would like each animated text to stay there after appearing and wait until all the text has appeared, then all text should disappear and restart again.(so basically instead of each text disappearing after flying in, it should stay visible only until the last text element has appeared, then restart all over)

**JavaScript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container .flying-text').css({
        opacity: 0
    });
    $('.container .active-text').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        marginLeft: "250px"
    }, 4000);
    var int = setInterval(changeText, 5000);
    function changeText() {
        var $activeText = $(".container .active-text");
        var $nextText = $activeText.next();
        if ($activeText.next().length == 0) $nextText = $('.container .flying-text:first');
        $activeText.animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);
        $activeText.animate({
            marginLeft: "-100px"
        });
        $nextText.css({
            opacity: 0
        }).addClass('active-text').animate({
            opacity: 1,
            marginLeft: "250px"
        }, 3000, function() {
            $activeText.removeClass('active-text');
        });
    }
});​
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{

    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#FFF;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

    .flying-text{
    margin-left:-100px;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flying-text active-text">I believe</div>                        
    <div class="flying-text">I can</div>                        
    <div class="flying-text">Fly</div>                      
</div>
```

Thank You for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the fade out code that runs each time.

```
function changeText() {

    var $activeText = $(".container .active-text");

    var $nextText = $activeText.next();
    if ($activeText.next().length == 0) {
        $nextText = $('.container .flying-text:first');

        // To fade all out _ MOVED FROM OUTSIDE THIS IF
        var $allText = $(".container div");
        $allText .animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);
        $allText .animate({
            marginLeft: "-100px"
        });
    }

    $nextText.css({
        opacity: 0
    }).addClass('active-text').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        marginLeft: "250px"
    }, 3000, function() {
        $activeText.removeClass('active-text');
    });
}​
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBehg/1/) to illustrate.

**UPDATE**
Based on some comments, I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBehg/4/) to show how you could use jQuery UI effects.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help. Do you perhaps know how to animate the text to implode instead of slide? Or is it way different from the code used here?

Comment: Any way to stop the animation when hovering over the text?

Comment: @DextrousDave - You are welcome. Check out [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) and [toggle effects](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects). There is no implode effect, only an explode - though there could be a plugin for an implode effect out there somewhere.

Comment: so the explode effect can be doen with the .animate function right? Thanks for your help again, super! useful